# solve for f(x) at a point with specific interval, another point and the first derivative.

Tags: derivatives

If  $f$  is a continuously differentiable real-valued function defined on the open interval $( -1 , 4 )$ such that $f (3) = 5$ and $f^\prime(x) \geq -1$ for all $x$,

what's the greatest possible value of $f (0)$ ?

I need to know how should I start and the procedure for getting the solution.

Comment: What would $f(0)$ be if $f'(x)=-1$ for all $x$? Can $f(0)$ be larger then this?

Comment: Thank you for the hint! 
It's 8.
After the solution, It seems very easy :))